# Mongodb: Array containing value and not containing another one

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to check in ON PUT event if there is record in database that contains the same MobilePhone (or it's 9 lat digits) that belongs to another user (another CardNumber). If so, I don't want commit new data. 
I'm trying to use code below, but it's not working. If condition is always true.
I'm not sure if I'm using brackets properly.

```
if(this.MobilePhone !== '' &&
db.mobile.find({$and:[
    {$in:[
        {"mobileuser.MobilePhone":this.MobilePhone.right(9)}, 
        {"mobileuser.MobilePhone":this.MobilePhone}]}, 
    {"mobileuser.CardNumber":{$ne:this.CardNumber}}]}).count() > 0)
{
cancel("MobilePhone is reserved by another user", 403);
}
```

Could you please check syntax and help me making it work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that $in part is wrong
Syntax for $in is

```
{ field: { $in: [<value1>, <value2>, ... <valueN> ] } }
```

Is it possible though that you would like to use "$or" instead ?

> ....that contains the same MobilePhone (or it's 9 last digits).....

```
db.mobile.find(
    {$and:[
            {
                $or:[
                        {"mobileuser.MobilePhone":this.MobilePhone.right(9)}, 
                        {"mobileuser.MobilePhone":this.MobilePhone}
                    ]
            }, 
            {"mobileuser.CardNumber":{$ne:this.CardNumber}}
        ]
    }
)
```